# I want to exclude an observation / tuple from my ggplots. I only want to show each country and not the world total

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(trade,aes(x='',y=value,fill=factor(countries)))+
  geom_bar(width=1,stat='identity')+
  coord_polar(theta = 'y',start=0)+
  labs(title = 'Dairy products imported',y='Dollar amount in 1000\'s' )
```

I do not want the world portion to show on my pie chart, however i do not
want to remove it completely from my data frame because it is relevant for my other charts.

[image: Pie chart result including world data]

Sample data

```
1                     World 2010 463000
2                    France 2010 145000
3               New Zealand 2010 191000
4  United States of America 2010 126000
5                   Denmark 2010      0
6                   Ireland 2010      0
7       Trinidad and Tobago 2010      0
8                     World 2011 525000
9                    France 2011 266000
10              New Zealand 2011 122000
```

Comment: `trade %>% filter(countries != "World") %>% ggplot(aes(x=...`

Comment: You can remove it from the data you give to this `ggplot` without "saving" (assigning) the removal in your data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `filter()` out the observations where countries is world. Using dplyr, pipe that into your ggplot call.

```
trade %>% 
  filter(countries != "World") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x='',y=value,fill=factor(countries)))+
  geom_bar(width=1,stat='identity')+
  coord_polar(theta = 'y',start=0)+
  labs(title = 'Dairy products imported',y='Dollar amount in 1000\'s' )
```

A base R version would be

```
ggplot(trade[trade$countries!="World",], aes(x='',y=value,fill=factor(countries)))+
  geom_bar(width=1,stat='identity')+
  coord_polar(theta = 'y',start=0)+
  labs(title = 'Dairy products imported',y='Dollar amount in 1000\'s' )
```

You simply are filtering/subsetting data using a logical operation where `!=` means not equal to.